# Google App Engine is not finding files in go runtime

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-platform

After adding a go.mod file, I am not able to access HTML template files from golang on App Engine. Everything works locally.

I have verified that the HTML files exist on App Engine using Stackdriver Debug, but the runtime is not seeing them. Here is the code I have.

```golang
var templates map[string]*htmltpl.Template

func init() {
    if templates == nil {
        templates = make(map[string]*htmltpl.Template)
    }

    templatesDir := getTemplatesDir()

    layouts, err := filepath.Glob(templatesDir + "/layouts/*.html")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    includes, err := filepath.Glob(templatesDir + "/includes/*.html")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Generate our templates map from our layouts/ and includes/ directories
    for _, layout := range layouts {
        files := append(includes, layout)
        templates[filepath.Base(layout)] = htmltpl.Must(htmltpl.ParseFiles(files...))
    }
}

func getTemplatesDir() string {
    _, filename, _, ok := runtime.Caller(1)
    if !ok {
        panic("Could not get filename")
    }
    dirpath := path.Join(path.Dir(filename), "../../templates")
    return dirpath
}
```

Here is my `app.yaml`:

```
runtime: go111

main: ./main

handlers:
  - url: .*
    script: auto
    secure: always
```

And here is my directory structure:

```
.
├── app.yaml
├── db/
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── handlers/
├── main
│   └── main.go
├── middleware/
├── models/
├── static/
├── templates/
│   ├── includes
│   │   ├── base.html
│   │   ├── button.html
│   │   ├── message.html
│   │   └── profile.html
│   └── layouts
│       └── thread.html
└── utils
    └── template
        └── template.go
```

I don't understand why, on App Engine, the call to `filepath.Glob(templatesDir + "/layouts/*.html")` returns an empty slice, whereas it returns a slice containing the path to `thread.html` when running locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `runtime.Caller()` returns the compile time source file path. The application is not run in the same directory as where it was compiled.

The application runs with the current working directory set to the directory containing app.yaml. Use this function to get the templates directory:

```
func getTemplatesDir() string {
    return "templates"
}
```